# The 14 standard PDF fonts and character encoding

Tags: pdf, fonts, postscript

I'm having difficulty producing PDFs that make use of the 14 standard PDF fonts. Let's use Times-Roman as an example.

I create a `Font` dictionary of type `Type1`, with `BaseFont` set to `Times-Roman`. If I omit the `Encoding` entry to the `Font` dictionary, or add an `Encoding` dictionary without a `BaseEncoding` set, the PDF viewer application should use the font's built-in encoding. For Times-Roman, this is *AdobeStandardEncoding*.

This works fine for ASCII characters. However, something more exotic like the 'fi' ligature (AdobeStandardEncoding code 174) is not displayed correctly by all PDF viewers:

- Adobe Reader shows ® (unicode index 174) for Times-Roman and Ă for Times-Italic
- SumatraPDF (wine) shows ® for both fonts
- Mozilla's PDF.js shows the 'AE' ligature both fonts

All other PDF viewers I've tried, display the 'fi' ligature properly. They also display the € symbol correctly, which is additionally mapped using the `Differences` array in the `Encoding` dictionary (because it is not included in AdobeStandardEncoding):

- Apple Preview/Skim
- GhostScript
- PDF-XChange Viewer (wine)
- Foxit Reader (wine)
- Chromium's internal PDF viewer
- Evince (homebrew)

Opening Adobe Reader's *Document Properties* window shows:

```
Times-Roman
    Type: Type1
    Encoding: Custom
    Actual Font: Times-Roman
    Actual Font Type: TrueType
```

I suspect the fact that a TrueType font is being used instead of a Type1 font might be related to the problem. The PDF specification:

> **StandardEncoding**  Adobe standard Latin-text encoding. This is the 
>   built-in encoding defined in Type 1 Latin-text font programs (but
>   *generally not in TrueType font programs*).

It also says **WinAnsiEncoding** and **MacRomanEncoding** *can* be used with TrueType fonts. So should we avoid using the built-in or **StandardEncoding** for the standard 14 fonts? Its effects seem to be undefined. It seems Adobe Reader doesn't bother performing a proper mapping from glyph names to glyphs in the TrueType font being used.

Will providing a `Differences` array when using the Win or Mac encodings produce proper results? Since these map codepoints to Type1/Postscript glyphs names, there is no direct link to TrueType glyphs.

**EDIT** Mmm, I have a feeling the Font Descriptor Flags might be important for these standard fonts. I set the flags to 4 up to now for all fonts, which seemed to work fine for True/OpenType fonts.

Comment: Please take into consideration that the standard 14 fonts are not exactly the real font programs used for them.  They are abstractions which in different viewers may be backed by different actual fonts.  Thus, counting on some standard encoding is s sure way to fail on some viewer or another, or in some version or another of the same one. Furthermore, the special treatment of standard fonts had long since been declared deprecated anyways...

Comment: @mkl It seems to work well across all PDF viewers listed above now that I set the *Nonsymbolic* flag. And the way I understand the spec, the special treatment of the standard fonts only relates to the `FirstChar`, `LastChar`, `Widths`, and `FontDescriptor` entries in the `Fonts` dictionary. You can still make use of the 14 standard fonts without having to embed them, as long as these entries are included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the `Flags` in the `FontDescriptor` dictionary is important. For Times, the *Nonsymbolic* flag (bit 6) needs to be set. The fact that Times is actually being typeset using a TrueType font has nothing to do with it.

To use the built-in encoding of the font, the `Encoding` entry of the Type1 `Font` dictionary should not be set. You may only add an `Encoding` dictionary (with `BaseEncoding` omitted) if it contains a non-empty `Differences` array, or Adobe Reader will error.

With these precautions, the generated PDF displays correctly on all 9 viewer applications listed above.

Comment: That's specified in [PDF 32000:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) Table 114 - Entries in an encoding Dictionary `BaseEncoding (Optional) - The base encoding—that is, the encoding from which the Differences entry (if present) describes differences— shall be the name of one of the predefined encodings MacRomanEncoding, MacExpertEncoding, or WinAnsiEncoding.
If this entry is absent, the Differences entry shall describe differences from an implicit base encoding.`

Comment: @dwarring I'm not sure what you meant to say, but I've updated my answer with how I think the differences should be handled.

Comment: Should it behave the same in all viewers if I don't specify the `FontDescriptor` dictionary at all (as is allowed for the 14 standard fonts)?