# Outputting UTF-8 encoded text strings in the pdf 2.0 spec

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to understand how to generate PDFs with utf-8 encoded strings and have been handcrafting a pdf file. I've been starting with the very simple file below and adjusting the instruction in the text stream (fixing the offsets etc for each test). Currently the text is "printed" to the rendered page with:

```
239 187 191 (test åäö abc) Tj
```

However, this renders as "test ˆ¥ˆ⁄ˆ¶ abc" on the page. In some [sample pdf](https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf20examples/blob/master/pdf20-utf8-test.pdf) I've found they render a rainbow as part of the document outline (not visible on the page). There they've used byte strings instead:

```
<EF BB BF F0 9F 8C 88 EF B8 8F 0A>
```

but using that with the `Tj` directive only outputs a couple of garbled characters and trying it with the hex encoding for åäö `<EF BB BF F0 9F 8C 88 EF B8 8F 0A>` yields the same result.

**How can I construct a pdf file containing utf-8 encoded string that is rendered properly (as long as the font supports those characters/glyphs)?**

Here is the full file content I've experimented with:

```
%PDF-2.0
1 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Pages
  /MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
  /Count 1
  /Kids [ 3 0 R ]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Parent 2 0 R
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F1 4 0 R 
    >>
  >>
  /Contents 5 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Font
  /Subtype /Type1
  /BaseFont/Helvetica
>> 
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
  /Length 66
>>
stream
BT
70 791.89 TD<F9>
/F1 12 Tf
239 187 191 (test åäö abc) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

xref
0 6
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000063 00000 n 
0000000161 00000 n 
0000000289 00000 n 
0000000365 00000 n 
trailer
<<
  /Size 6
  /Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
484
%%EOF
```

Comment: Using UTF-8 encoded strings in content streams does not work in general. The elements of those strings represent single glyphs to be drawn in left-to-right or top-to-bottom direction (depending on the encoding) which does not match Unicode.

Comment: By the way, seeing `239 187 191 (test åäö abc) Tj`, those leading numbers are invalid, **Tj** only has a string parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use version 2.0 for a simplified method without font embeddings. The Sample linked to may contain UTF-8 but even recent Acrobat and Windows cannot make sense of those characters. The filename and contents are not understood.

[image]

The Main problem is that ANSI Helvetica Plain Text will render like `ˆ¥ˆ⁄ˆ¶` whereas WinAnsiEncoding Arial font would look Like `åäö` `<E5E4F6>`.

We can actually use 1.0 Helvetica methods by use the octal values decimal 64 = \100 or = hex <40> and hex is the easier to lookup so e5=å

This does mean you need a method to convert into Unicode and without embedding CIDs or CMAPs that can be done by add a Unicode Font Name like MS Arial. Here is your example as version 1.X but labelled compatible with 2.0 readers! Always use the lowest number it should be perhaps 1.2 or say 1.4 with transparency only higher if needed for more modern constructs, so most commonly 1.7.

[image]

```
%PDF-2.0
%¿¾½¼
1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/MediaBox[0 0 595.28 841.89]/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F0 4 0 R/F1 5 0 R>>>>/Contents 6 0 R>> endobj
4 0 obj <</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>> endobj
5 0 obj <</BaseFont/Arial/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 228/LastChar 246/Subtype/TrueType/Type/Font/Widths[556 556 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 556]>> endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 83>>
stream
BT
70 791.89 TD
/F0 12 Tf
(test ) Tj
/F1 12 Tf
[<E5E4F6>] TJ
/F0 12 Tf
( abc) Tj
ET

endstream
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000139 00000 n 
0000000238 00000 n 
0000000301 00000 n 
0000000467 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
600
%%EOF
```

Binary copy for download currently at https://docdro.id/b3CPljN

In comments you asked can such a method be used for other languages, and generally single HEX codes are limited in range to some European characters but not all.  The next step up is "Fonts with Double Bytes" eg. TTF. Many single language fonts such as Chinese fit just inside that limit. However normally DO need supportive font embedding.

[image]

The binary file will be too complex to show here, and this file was massaged in MS Notepad to include a suitable decompressed TTF (thus it could fail in most viewers like Docdroid download here https://www.docdroid.net/GFVU0Ms/testmixedchars-pdf

[image]

needing the true compressed binary fonts). It may on occasion only work in ones that substitute for poor CID/CMAPs, like the one I support.

The key point to note is that there is only ONE character `<0c26>` that looks like TWO, much the same as European ligatures like double `ﬀ`.

That Character ID (CID) is then Character MAPped (CMAP) within the font definition (9 0 obj).

There that placement CID code is altered by `/ToUnicode 9 0 R`
`<0C26> <7684>` https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=7684
and it is that Unicode that should be used for extraction whilst the Font provides the display Glyph(s)

PDF is paint by numbers so you can have lots of placements on the page such as

```
/F2 12 Tf
1 0 0 1 22.68 0 Tm
<0000> Tj
```

and if the mapping is `<0000> <7684>` then that Unicode character will appear in ink at all those locations. Hence PDF itself is not using Unicode as such for placements, in Version 1.X (nor does it have to use 2.0 methods).

Comment: Would this approach work with other non-latin unicode text, eg. Thai or Arabic or a mix thereof? I got the impression from the spec that utf-8 text strings needed so.e prefix bytes. Does this approach leave that out and use the fonts unicode glyph codes instead? Not sure if my questions make sense, too new to the area :)

Answer (score 2):

To quote the standard:

"A string operand of a text-showing operator shall be interpreted as a sequence of character codes identifying the glyphs to be painted.

With a simple font, each byte of the string shall be treated as a separate character code. The character code shall then be looked up in the font’s encoding to select the glyph, as described in 9.6.5, "Character encoding"

With a composite font (PDF 1.2), multiple-byte codes may be used to select glyphs. In this instance, one or more consecutive bytes of the string shall be treated as a single character code. The code lengths and the mappings from codes to glyphs are defined in a data structure called a CMap, described in 9.7, "Composite fonts""

You will notice no mention of Unicode or UTF8 there.

Now, you may find many PDFs in which the operand of Tj looks for all the world like an ASCII string - but this is misleading - it is simply that the font encoding makes it so. You may even find documents where non-ASCII characters (e.g accented letters) appear to look like UTF8 but again, it isn't true. The font encoding is simply arranged to make it so.

So, the question then is - using the standard built-in font Helvetica, can you modify the mapping so that your Tj string looks like UTF8. But this question is at least as hard to answer as simply looking up the PDF StandardEncoding which is what you are (unknowingly) using, and outputting appropriate bytes in the Tj string.

You can find the StandardEncoding, along with the others, in Appendix D of the standard.

(Actually, for reasons explained in the following link, you're better off specifying WinAnsiEncoding or MacRomanEncoding in your font dictionary: [The 14 standard PDF fonts and character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486716/the-14-standard-pdf-fonts-and-character-encoding))